# Битрикс ищет не все товары

Tags: битрикс

В строке поиска по слову "тонометр" показываются только 8 результатов, на самом деле их больше.

Если вбить "Тонометр Onelife L-1 ECO автомат", то в результатах он есть, а в первом случае - нет.

Переиндексацию сделал. Что еще настроить, пока не могу сообразить.

Comment: *Если вбить "Тонометр Onelife L-1 ECO автомат", то в результатах он есть, а в первом случае - нет.* Начни с проверки, не затесался ли в название символ на латинице, например...

Comment: Переписал на кириллице, переиндексировал. Результат тот же.

Comment: Где показываются 8 результатов? На странице результатов или в выпадашке под строкой поиска? Если в выпадашке, то там надо настраивать сколько результатов показывать. И понятно что 100500 результатов в выпадашке никому не нужны. Если на странице результатов, то ковыряйте модуль "Поиск" в административном разделе в "настройки модулей"-"поиск" или как-то так.

Comment: На странице результатов. Копал настройки модуля, но не нашел настроек по кол-ву результатов. Да врядли это от настроек по кол-ву зависит. Например, по "ингалятор" находится 10 элементов.